# Django background image disappear

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to add the background image to my website.

**settings.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

**path about the file:**

```
project/app
       /static/css/base.css
              /images/img.jpg
```

I tried the two ways,respectively int the html and css.

**add in html:**

*html:*

```
{% load static %}
<section style:"background-image: url({% static "images/img.jpg" %})"></section>
```

**add in css:**

*html:*

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section id="intro-header"></section>
```

*css:*

```
section#intro-header{
background-image: url({% static "images/img.jpg" %});
background-size: cover;
}
```

Both of them don't work.

Which part I missed?

**update**

here is the system message:

```
"GET /images/img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2387
```

**update**

When I　put

```
    <style>
    section#intro-header{
           background-image: url("/static/images/winter.jpg");
           background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
```

in the html file and it works

But the css problem still exisits.

**update**

Thanks everyone

In **add in css**

turn into  `<link href="/static/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Then it works,although {{ STATIC_URL }} equals with '/static/'

or the thing I missed?

Comment: Can you see the image by going directly to `/static/images/img.jpg`?

Comment: yes,the image does work.I updated the system message above about 404 not found

Comment: Did you try replacing the double quotes with single quotes?

Comment: I have tried but still don't work

Comment: What is you Django version? Are we talking about your development environment or your production environment?

Comment: 1.8.13 development environment

Comment: In stead of hardcoding the url, you can also make use of the {% static %} template tag -> {% static 'css/base.css' %}

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your URL's to include static files in development?

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I didn't add it but finally work. so is it necessary?

Comment: No this is not necessary, but does allow you to use your static files in development when the django.contrib.staticfiles middleware is not installed